# haproxy acl - accept only from specific IPs

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

I've got haproxy and need to provide smtp to servers which does not have direct connection.

Here is portion of my config:

```
listen smtp     10.12.23.10:3025
    mode tcp
    server smtp     172.30.33.12:25
    #tcp-request inspect-delay 2s
    acl white_list src 10.146.5.247 10.146.5.201
    tcp-request content accept if white_list
    tcp-request content reject
```

Any attempt to connect to the port are rejected. If I remove line `tcp-request content reject` - works for everyone, but haproxy by default accepts everything. 
What is correct way of letting in only two or more servers in?

I've tried following lines as well:

```
tcp-request content reject unless whitelist
tcp-request content reject if !whitelist
```

I have haproxy 1.4.18, if helps.

Comment: Do you have any NATing done before the clients and haproxy? Can you confirm that the requests are really coming from the indicated source IPs? `tcpdump` or `wireshark` can confirm this to you on haproxy node.

Comment: @Khaled there is no NATing between hosts. Requests are coming from those IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to haproxy 1.4.22 resolved issue.

Answer (score 4):

The con below works as expected for me on haproxy 1.4.15.

```
listen smtp   :3025
    mode tcp
    server smtp  192.168.1.2:25
    acl white_list src 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.205
    tcp-request inspect-delay 2s
    tcp-request content accept if white_list
    tcp-request content reject
```

You can even remove the inspect delay line, but the clients would be rejected after the "timeout connect".

```
listen smtp   :3025
    mode tcp
    server smtp  192.168.1.2:25
    acl white_list src 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.205
    timeout connect 1s
#    tcp-request inspect-delay 2s
    tcp-request content accept if white_list
    tcp-request content reject
```